# How many connections/s can I expect between PHP and MySQL on separate server?

Tags: php, performance, networking, sockets

Trying to separate out my LAMP application into two servers, one for php and one for mysql. So far the application connects locally through a file socket and works fine.

I'm worried about the number connections I can establish if it is over the network. I have been testing tcp connections on unix for benchmark purposes and I **know** that you cannot exceed a certain amount of connections per second otherwise it halts due to the lack of resources (be it sockets, or file handles or whatever). *I also understand that php does not implement connection pooling so for each page load a new connection over the network must be made. I also looked into pconnect for php and it seems to bring more problems.*

I know this is a very very common setup (php+mysql), can anyone provide some typical usage and statistics they get out of their servers? Thanks!

---

The problem is not related to running out of connections allowed my MySQL. The main problem is that unix **cannot** very quickly create and tear down tcp connections. Sockets end up in TIME_WAIT and you have to wait for a period before you free up more sockets to connect again. These two screenshots clearly shows this pattern. MySQL does work up to a certain point and then pauses because the web server ran out of sockets. After certain amount of time passed, the web server was able to make new connections.

[alt text http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/3809/picture4k.png](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/3809/picture4k.png)

[alt text http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/4580/picture2uyw.png](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/4580/picture2uyw.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the limit is at 65535. So you'd have to have 65535 connections at the same time to hit that limit since a regular mysql connection closes automatically.

[mysql_connect()](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

> Note: The link to the server will be closed as soon as the execution of the script ends, unless it's closed earlier by explicitly calling mysql_close().

But if you're using a [persistent mysql connection](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php), then you can run into trouble.

> Using persistent connections can require a bit of tuning of your Apache and MySQL configurations to ensure that you do not exceed the number of connections allowed by MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Each MySQL connection actually uses several meg of ram for various buffers, and takes a while to set up, which is why MySQL is limited to 100 concurrent open connections by default.  You can up that limit, but it's better to spend your time trying to limit concurrent connections, via various methods.

Beware of raising the connection limit too high, as you can run out of memory (which, I believe, crashes mysql), or you may push important things out of memory.  e.g. MySQL's performance is highly dependent on the OS automatically caching the data it reads from disk in memory; if you set your connection limit too high, you'll be contending for memory with the cache.

If you don't up your connection limit, you'll run out of connections long before your run out of sockets/file handles/etc.  If you do increase your connection limit, you'll run out of RAM long before you run out of sockets/file handles/etc.

Regarding limiting concurrent connections:

1. Use a connection pooling solution.  You're right, there isn't one built in to PHP, but there are plenty of standalone ones out there to choose from.  This saves expensive connection setup/tear down time.
2. Only open database connections when you absolutely need them.  In my current project, we automatically open a database connection when the first query is issued, and not a moment before; we also release the connection after we've done all our database work, but before the page's HTML is actually generated.  The shorter the period of time you hold connections open, the fewer connections will be open simultaneously.
3. Cache what you can in a lighter-weight solution like memcached.  My current project temporarily caches pages displayed to anonymous users (since every anonymous user gets the same HTML, in the end -- why bother running the same database queries all over again a few scant milliseconds later?), meaning no database connection is necessary at all.  This is especially useful for bursts of anonymous traffic, like a front-page digg.

Comment: Connection pooling, caching to avoid database queries, and only opening database connections when you actually need to query will help with the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: Can you recommend some connection pooling solutions/software?